# Tensorflow MultiRNNCell LSTM: “'Tensor' object is not iterable”

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I have the following code:

```
self.inputs = tf.placeholder(shape=[None, num_inputs], dtype=tf.float32)

# Recurrent network for temporal dependencies
def make_cell(units):
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(units, state_is_tuple=True)
    if mode == TRAIN and keep_prob < 1:
        cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=keep_prob)
        return cell

num_units = [h_size, h_size]
multi_rnn_cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(
    [make_cell(n) for n in num_units], state_is_tuple=True)

self.state_init = multi_rnn_cell.zero_state(1, tf.float32)
h_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, h_size])
c_in = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, h_size])
self.state_in = (c_in, h_in)
state_in = tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMStateTuple(c_in, h_in)

rnn_in = tf.expand_dims(self.inputs, [0])
lstm_outputs, lstm_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(
    cell=multi_rnn_cell, inputs=rnn_in, initial_state=state_in, dtype=tf.float32)
```

When I run it, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.

When I run the same code, but with just 1 LSTMCell and without expanding dimansions, it runs just fine.

I would like to run using more than just one layer by adding MultiRNNCell.

Can someone help me?

Comment: I think the problem lies at the way you create `state_in`. You are using a multiRNNCell with a list of cells. So `state_in` should be a list with that many `LSTMStateTuple` objects, not a single `LSTMStateTuple`.